# Is there *really* no native term for "stoning"?

Tags: translation

I always find it hard to believe that there is no native Chinese term for **stoning**.

Chinese execution methods are numerous and varied: 凌迟, 车裂, 斩首, 炮烙, etc, etc.

Stoning always gets translated as: 用石头砸, 拿石头打死, 用石头砸死, 被乱石砸死.

Is there really no native term for stoning? No equivalent execution method? Too pedestrian for the Chinese?

Comment: 中国古代有一种针对出轨女性的刑罚叫作“沉塘”，就是把女人和石头关进一个笼子，让笼子沉到水里。对于扔石头的刑罚，没有听说过。

Comment: I think the title should be "Is stoning part of Chinese historical execution method" (which I think is not particularly relevant in this forum). Chinese characters are morphemes, so new words (native terms) can be created easily, eg 石刑，炮决，犬决.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it does.

We called it 石刑。

Please refer to:[English Stoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoning)

[Chinese Stoning](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E7%9F%B3%E5%88%91)

Comment: What's up with all these weird translations then?

Comment: Please refresh the page to see again.

Comment: Those are the explanation. Like  石刑，即用石头砸,、拿石头打死、 用石头砸死,、被乱石砸死。

Comment: "Natives term", means it is part of the culture.  Apparently the answer given is a translated term.

Answer (score 0):

Stoning is rare in the China culture.

First, Chinese society enters imperial dynasty(monarchy) one thousand years earlier than Europe.

Second, this is not because it is more "humane", but imperialism government wants to monopoly the power of capital punishment, with the hope of preventing the people enact the idea of hurling the stones toward the rulers.

Even these may happen during a rebellion, but this is not considered as "punishment".

Comment: Agree, stoning is a common method of mob justice, the imperial courts of China which held all the power, wouldn't allow common people to have the power to carry out capital punishment themselves.

Comment: I thought China considered stoning too pedestrian

Comment: @user3306356  Dictatorship hates competition.

Comment: This answer and these comments seem completely unrelated to question and the Chinese language.